# crawl robots and page size

Tags: http, web-crawler

was wondering, does a web site get affected in terms of search engine rank or results positioning, if its size is not optimized but instead it has average loading times comparing with the same type of websites. lets say

```
No Cache:
289.0K  Total size
35      HTTP requests
```

Comment: 289K and 35 HTTP requests makes it sound like you're including JS/CSS/images in your totals, which is misleading when it comes to search engine bots - they only look at the page's HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engine rank is determined by keywords used in the links (predominantly from other sites).  Size of your page is relatively irrelevant.